# How to add HTTP header to downloadurl in wix toolset?

Tags: wix

Is there any option to add http headers to downloadurl of MsiPackage element?

```
 <MsiPackage
    SourceFile="path/to/file.msi"
    DownloadUrl="url/to/file.msi"
    Compressed="no" 
      >
</MsiPackage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Burn doesn't support adding headers to payload download requests.